# How to return positions from IBKR API (interactive brokers) consistently?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

IBKR gives me horribly inconsistent results so far, I hope it's just because I don't understand something.

Here is my code to try to get my account positions, but it only worked the first time I ran it, and doesn't work anymore. I find that half of the things I try to do on IBKR are this way... Is there like a simpler API that doesn't require me instantiating classes to simply get a list of positions in my account? Thanks guys.

> def read_positions(): #read all accounts positions and return
> DataFrame with information
>
> ```
> from ibapi.client import EClient 
> from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
> from ibapi.common import TickerId
> import pandas as pd
>
> class ib_class(EWrapper, EClient): 
>     def __init__(self): 
>         EClient.__init__(self, self)
>         self.all_positions = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ['Account','Symbol', 'Quantity', 'Average Cost'])
>
>     def position(self, account, contract, pos, avgCost):
>         index = str(account)+str(contract.symbol)
>         self.all_positions.loc[index]=account,contract.symbol,pos,avgCost
>
>     def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str):
>         if reqId > -1:
>             print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)
>
>     def positionEnd(self):
>         super().positionEnd()
>         self.disconnect()
>
> ib_api = ib_class() 
> ib_api.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0) 
> ib_api.reqPositions()
> current_positions = ib_api.all_positions
> ib_api.run()
>
> return(current_positions)
> ```

Comment: can you share the IBKR api documentation link?

Comment: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/introduction.html

Comment: Your code works as expected. If it worked once only then you either did not disconnect properly or you have other connections to the gateway still connected. What is the error you receive? IB API itself is quite consistent and this sort of an issue is not common.

Answer (score 1):

IB doesn't respond to `reqPositions` instantly, so you should wait a second or two before accessing the result. Will this work for you?

```
import time
...

ib_api = ib_class() 
ib_api.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0) 
ib_api.run()
ib_api.reqPositions()
time.sleep(2)
current_positions = ib_api.all_positions
return(current_positions)
```

I'm not at my dev computer, so I can't verify that this works properly.

EDIT: Here's a short program that demonstrates how `reqPositions` can be used. I've tested that it works.

```
class ib_class(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self, addr, port, client_id):
        EClient. __init__(self, self)
        self.connect(addr, port, client_id)
        self.index = ''
        thread = Thread(target=self.run)
        thread.start()

    def position(self, account, contract, pos, avgCost):
        self.index = str(account) + str(contract.symbol)

ib_api = ib_class('127.0.0.1', 7497, 0)
ib_api.reqPositions()
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Index: ' + ib_api.index)
ib_api.disconnect()
```

Comment: good idea, but it's not working sadly

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a simple, working program.

Comment: Why do you have to run with threading? Why can't I just run it linearly for heavens sake

Comment: Because you don't know when IB's data will arrive. You need to create a separate thread to receive IB's data.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, which seems to be caused by the newer TWS version.  With TWS 1012 positions come back consistently 100% of the time, with TWS 1019 50% of the time, 0 positions are returned.  I'm waiting 3 seconds in both cases:

```
ib_api.reqPositions()
time.sleep(3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While using a sleep time can address this challenge, waiting for 3 seconds in a production environment to obtain positions and potentially follow up with placing an order is impractical. A more effective approach is to wait for the event to complete, which can also be applied to "most" IB functions.

```
import threading

class ib_class(EWrapper, EClient): 
    def __init__(self): 
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.all_positions = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ['Account','Symbol', 'Quantity', 'Average Cost'])
        self.execution_event = threading.Event()

    def position(self, account, contract, pos, avgCost):
        index = str(account)+str(contract.symbol)
        self.all_positions.loc[index]=account,contract.symbol,pos,avgCost
        # set the event
        self.positions_event.set()

    def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str):
        if reqId > -1:
            print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)
        # set the event
        self.positions_event.set()

    def positionEnd(self):
        super().positionEnd()
        self.disconnect()

ib_api = ib_class() 
ib_api.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0) 

ib_api.positions_event.clear() # reset positions_event
ib_api.reqPositions()
ib_api.positions_event.wait()  # Wait for positions data to come in
current_positions = ib_api.all_positions
ib_api.run()

return(current_positions)
```